# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object. I Have check all Possible ways but not getting solution

Tags: apex, visualforce

1. Create Qoute  from Opportunity
2. Create Quote line item from opportunity line item.
3. qoutebt is the button on qoute line item to create qoute line item from opportunity line item.

All are custom object, below is the code

**VF Page:**

```html
<apex:page controller="qoutebt">
 <apex:form >
 <apex:sectionHeader title="Qoute" subtitle="Qoute Information"/>
 <apex:pageBlock >
 
  <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
   <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Save}"/>
   <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
 
 <apex:pageBlockSection title="Qoute Information">
 
  <apex:inputField value="{!qte.Name}" required="true"/>
  
  <apex:inputField value="{!opp.name}"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!opp.Account__c}"/>
  
  <apex:inputField value="{!qte.Stage__c}"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!qte.Type__c}"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!qte.Phone__c}"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!qte.Fax__c}"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!qte.Amount__c}"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!qte.Description__c}"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!qte.Lead_Source__c}"/>

 </apex:pageBlockSection>
 
  <apex:pageBlockSection title="Opportunity Line Items">
  
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!opplist}" var="opl">
    
        <apex:column headerValue="Opportunety Name">
                <apex:inputField value="{!opl.name}"/>
        </apex:column>
    
        <apex:column headerValue="Producct">
                <apex:inputField value="{!opl.Producct__c}"/>
        </apex:column>
    
        <apex:column headerValue="Quantity">
                <apex:inputField value="{!opl.Quantity__c}"/>
        </apex:column> 
    
        <apex:column headerValue="Unit Price">
                <apex:inputField value="{!opl.Unit_Price__c}"/>
        </apex:column>
    
        <apex:column headerValue="Producct Description">
                <apex:inputField value="{!opl.Producct_Description__c}"/>
        </apex:column>
    
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
    
  </apex:pageBlockSection>

 
  </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex Class:**

```java
public class qoutebt {

    public string ids{get;set;}
    public qoute__c qte{get;set;}
    public opportunety__c opp{get;set;}
    public qoute_line_item__c qlic{get;set;}
    public List<Qoute_line_item__c> qlilist{get;set;}


    public List<Opportunety_line_item__c> opplist{get;set;}

    public qoutebt(){

        ids=Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        system.debug(ids);

        List<Opportunety_line_item__c> opplist=  new List<Opportunety_line_item__c>();
        opplist= [select name, Producct__c,Quantity__c,Unit_Price__c,Producct_Description__c  from Opportunety_Line_Item__c where Opportunety__c=:ids];

        opp = new opportunety__c();
        opp = [select id, name, lead_source__c, type__c, account__c, stage__c, amount__c from Opportunety__c where id=:ids];

        qte = new qoute__c();

        qte.amount__c = opp.amount__c;
        qte.lead_source__c= opp.lead_source__c;
        qte.type__c= opp.type__c;

        for(opportunety_line_item__c oli : opplist){
            
            qlic = new qoute_line_item__c();
                
             qlic.Opportunety_line_item__c = oli.id;
             qlic.Unit_Price__c = oli.Unit_Price__c;
             qlic.Quantity__c = oli.Quantity__c;
             qlic.Producct__c = oli.Producct__c;
             qlic.Producct_Description__c = oli.Producct_Description__c;

             qlilist.add(qlic);

        }

    }

    public pagereference save(){

        update opplist;

        qoute__c qt = new qoute__c();
        qt.opportunety__c=ids;
        insert qt;
                  
                    
        for(Qoute_line_item__c qlic :qlilist){
            qlic.qoute__c = qt.Id;
        }

        insert qlilist;

                
        pagereference pr = new pagereference('/'+ ids);
        return pr;
    }

    public pagereference cancel(){
        pagereference pr = new pagereference('/'+ ids);
        return pr;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Opportunety_line_item__c> opplist=  new List<Opportunety_line_item__c>();
```

Creates a locally scoped variable that *shadows* the class variable (see [Name Shadowing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_name_shadowing.htm)). Later, when you try to go to save the records, `opplist` will have never been set, causing the `NullPointerException`.

The solution is to remove that line of code.

Comment: Thank you for answering...but the nullpointer exception is showing on qlilist.add(qlic); and it is showing on saving class.

Comment: @DheerajD Yes, in addition, you do not have a `qliList = List<Qoute_line_item__c>()` anywhere in your code. You must initialize a variable before you can call any of its methods or access any of its properties.

Comment: Thank you very much, @sfdcfox I have crossed checked and  initialized later and it worked.